# Find all pair-wise diffs between elements in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

all.

I have a sorted time-series `my_ts`, and I need to find the pair-wise diffs (below some threshold called `horizon`) between **all** the elements of the series (and not just between consecutive elements).

I wrote the following code to do that, but as you can see, it applies *itertools*, which feels unnecessary within the pandas environment.

```
from itertools import combinations
my_ts = pd.Series(pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=6, freq='d'))

def count_gaps(ts, horizon):
    # returns counts of all gaps shorter than horizon
    diffs = ((t2-t1) for (t1, t2) in combinations(ts, 2) if t2-t1<=horizon)
    return pd.Series(diffs).value_counts()

count_gaps(my_ts, horizon=pd.to_timedelta(3, unit='d'))
```

Any suggestions for a more Pandaistic (and hopefully faster) solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can

```
s=pd.DataFrame(columns=my_ts,index=my_ts).apply(lambda x : x.name-x.index)

s.mask((s<pd.Timedelta('1 days'))|(s>pd.Timedelta('3 days'))).stack().value_counts()
Out[528]: 
1 days    5
2 days    4
3 days    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: @user3121900 yw :-) happy coding

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sensibly faster (about x100 in a quick benchmark below) NumPy solution:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def count_gaps1(ts, horizon):
    diffs = ts.values[:, np.newaxis] - ts.values[np.newaxis, :]
    idx, c = np.unique(diffs[(diffs > np.timedelta64(0)) & (diffs <= horizon.to_timedelta64())], return_counts=True)
    return pd.Series(c, idx)

my_ts = pd.Series(pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=6, freq='d'))
print(count_gaps(my_ts, horizon=pd.to_timedelta(3, unit='d')))
```

Output:

```
1 days    5
2 days    4
3 days    3
dtype: int64
```

IPython `%timeit` benchmark:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def count_gaps_original(ts, horizon):
    diffs = ((t2-t1) for (t1, t2) in itertools.combinations(ts, 2) if t2-t1<=horizon)
    return pd.Series(diffs).value_counts()

def count_gaps_Wen(ts, horizon):
    s = pd.DataFrame(columns=my_ts,index=my_ts).apply(lambda x : x.name-x.index)
    return s.mask((s < pd.Timedelta('1 days')) | (s > pd.Timedelta('3 days'))).stack().value_counts()

def count_gaps_jdehesa(ts, horizon):
    diffs = ts.values[:, np.newaxis] - ts.values[np.newaxis, :]
    idx, c = np.unique(diffs[(diffs > np.timedelta64(0)) & (diffs <= horizon.to_timedelta64())], return_counts=True)
    return pd.Series(c, idx)

my_ts = pd.Series(pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=100, freq='d'))
%timeit count_gaps_original(my_ts, horizon=pd.to_timedelta(3, unit='d'))
>>> 145 ms ± 1.87 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit count_gaps_Wen(my_ts, horizon=pd.to_timedelta(3, unit='d'))
>>> 44.1 ms ± 942 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit count_gaps_jdehesa(my_ts, horizon=pd.to_timedelta(3, unit='d'))
>>> 409 µs ± 9.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```